# Without creating a window, is it possible to detect the current XCB modifier state?

Tags: c, x11

I use the Xkb `sticky` option, and I would like to write a program that emits some text to stdout when the modifier key state changes, e.g. when Ctrl is "active" regardless of whether the physical Ctrl key is pressed. I want this program to be able to work without creating a visible X window and leaving it open, as that would obstruct my use of other applications.

Is this possible using the Xkb, XkbCommon, Xlib and/or XCB libraries? I tried using `XNextEvent` as suggested [in the Xkb spec](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/XKB/xkblib.html#interpreting_key_events), but this function just blocks forever.

My full attempt at an implementation is [here](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ewintershadows/keystatus/tree/5e19292a4f95a6b812fad874f218f98dfdd43256/src/keystatus.c), but this is the relevant portion:

```c
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

/* Various X and Xkb data that are often needed together */
typedef struct ExtensionInfo {
    Display* display;         /* An X display */
    int base_event_code;      /* Integer code offset for Xkb events */
    int base_err_code;        /* Integer code offset for Xkb errors */
    int xkb_version_major;    /* Dual-purpose version indicator; see XkbOpenDisplay(3) */
    int xkb_version_minor;    /* Dual-purpose version indicator; see XkbOpenDisplay(3) */
    int xkb_reason;           /* Error reason if XkbOpenDisplay fails, or success reason */
} ExtensionInfo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ExtensionInfo *extension_info;
    XkbEvent xkb_event;

    extension_info->display = XkbOpenDisplay(
        /* NULL here is allowed by XkbOpenDisplay but not mentioned explicitly
         * in the XkbOpenDisplay man page - it defaults to $DISPLAY */
        NULL,
        &(extension_info->base_event_code),
        &(extension_info->base_err_code),
        &(extension_info->xkb_version_major),
        &(extension_info->xkb_version_minor),
        &(extension_info->xkb_reason)
    );

    const unsigned long int xkb_details_mask = (
        XkbModifierBaseMask |
        XkbModifierStateMask |
        XkbModifierLatchMask |
        XkbModifierLockMask
    );

    bool xkb_initialized = XkbSelectEventDetails(
        extension_info->display,
        XkbUseCoreKbd,
        XkbStateNotifyMask,
        xkb_details_mask,
        xkb_details_mask
    );

    printf("Waiting...\n");
    XNextEvent(extension_info->display, &xkb_event.core);
    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general yes, it's perfectly possible to call any kind of X11 requests which need a Window handle (eg. for getting or setting the selection) *without* popping a window on the screen -- by creating an **`InputOnly`** window.

But for `Xkb*` you don't even need that. In the posted snippet, your problem is that you're not calling `XkbSelectEvents` at all, so no Xkb events will be delivered to your X11 client.

The little example below *does* get an event whenever the state changes:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(void){
        Display *dpy; int xkb_event;
        if(!(dpy = XkbOpenDisplay(0, &xkb_event, 0, 0, 0, 0)))
                errx(1, "cannot open display '%s'", XDisplayName(0));
        XkbSelectEvents(dpy, XkbUseCoreKbd, XkbStateNotifyMask,
                XkbStateNotifyMask);
        for(;;){
                XkbEvent e; XNextEvent(dpy, &e.core);
                if(e.type == xkb_event && e.any.xkb_type == XkbStateNotify)
                        warnx("xkb state changed!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Ah! The spec made it sound like `XkbSelectEvent` and `XkbSelectEventDetails` were interchangeable. I will try this.